# How to zoom images when they are in multiple pages in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, pinchzoom

I have a main scroll view and in that main scroll view I have a child scroll view which has UIImageView. I'm having a problem with zooming the scroll view properly. Whenever I attempt to zoom into the image, the view just moves around but the image is not zoomed in. I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Can someone please help me see what's wrong? Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    var seguedAlbumImagePathArray=[]
    var seguedCurrentImageIndex: Int?

    var imageView: UIView?
    var childScrollView: UIScrollView?
    var imagev: UIImageView?

    var totalPages: Int = 0

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        totalPages = seguedAlbumImagePathArray.count
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)

        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ImageViewerViewController.dismissImageViewer))
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap!)
    }

    func dismissImageViewer() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.scrollView.alpha=0
        })
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.13, target: self, selector: #selector(self.dismissView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func dismissView() {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
            let secondPresentingVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController;
            secondPresentingVC?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {})
        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        configureScrollView()
        configurePageControl()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }


    // MARK: Custom method implementation

    func configureScrollView() {

        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        // Enable paging.
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

        // Set the following flag values.
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.scrollsToTop = false

        // Set the scrollview content size.
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(totalPages), scrollView.frame.size.height)

        // Set self as the delegate of the scrollview.
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // Load the ImageView view from the ImageView.xib file and configure it properly.
        for i in 0 ..< totalPages {
            // Load the ImageView view.
            imageView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ImageView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

            imageView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            // Set its frame and the background color.
            imageView!.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
            //imageView.backgroundColor = sampleBGColors[i]

            // Set the proper message to the test view's label.
            let label = imageView!.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            label.text = "\(i + 1)/\(totalPages)"

            childScrollView = imageView!.viewWithTag(2) as? UIScrollView
            childScrollView?.minimumZoomScale=1.0
            childScrollView?.maximumZoomScale=6.0
            childScrollView?.delegate = self

            imagev = childScrollView!.viewWithTag(3) as? UIImageView
            view.sendSubviewToBack(imagev!)

            if let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(seguedAlbumImagePathArray[i] as! String),
                let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData as! NSData) {
                imagev!.image = imageToDisplay
            }
            else {
                ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(seguedAlbumImagePathArray[i] as! String, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
                    self.imagev!.image = image
                })
            }

            var frame: CGRect = scrollView.frame
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(seguedCurrentImageIndex!)
            frame.origin.y = 0
            scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: false)

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView!)
            //scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint, animated: true)
            print(scrollView.contentOffset)
        }
    }


    func configurePageControl() {
        // Set the total pages to the page control.
        pageControl.numberOfPages = totalPages

        // Set the initial page.
        pageControl.currentPage = seguedCurrentImageIndex!
    }


    // MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate method implementation

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Calculate the new page index depending on the content offset.
        let currentPage = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width);
        //1.025 = 328/320
        // Set the new page index to the page control.
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
    }


    // MARK: IBAction method implementation

    @IBAction func changePage(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Calculate the frame that should scroll to based on the page control current page.
        var newFrame = scrollView.frame
        newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.size.width * CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage)
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(newFrame, animated: true)

    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imagev
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when I put scrollview under a UIcontrolViewCOntroller. 
Remove this -

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imagev
    }
```

and use

```
  func viewForZooming( in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgview
    }
```

That worked for me.